# Topology Question Help

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets and let $f\colon X \to Y$ be a function.

(a) If there is a subset $V$ of $Y$ such that $f(f^{-1}(V))$ does not equal $V$, must there be a subset $A$ of $X$ such that $f^{-1}(f(A))$ does not equal $A$?

(b) If there is a subset $A$ of $X$ such that $f^{-1}(f(A))$ does not equal $A$, must there be a subset $V$ of $Y$ such that $f(f^{-1}(V))$ does not equal $V$?

Those are the questions.

Then I do this:

Let $X$ be the integers

Let $Y$ be the non-negative integers

Let $A$ be a subset of $X$ where $A =$ negative, even integers

Let $V$ be a subset of $Y$ where $V =$ positive, even integers

Let $f(x) = |x|$.

I'm not really sure what to do from here…

Edit:  Oh I apologize, I didn't mean to delete it.  Thank you!

Comment: There is a common name for functions $f$ such that $f(f^{-1}(V)) = V$ for every subset $V$ of $Y$. What is it? It might help a lot if you draw pictures. Similarly, there is a common name for functions $f$ that satisfy $f^{-1}(f(A)) = A$ for every subset $A$ of $X$. See if you can recognize those names first!

Comment: Instead of beginning with these specific sets, you’d do better to try to figure out under what circumstances it can happen that $f^{-1}[f[A]]\ne A$, and under what circumstances it can happen that $f[f^{-1}[V]]\ne V$. HINT: One of them has to do with whether $f$ is a surjection, and one has to do with whether $f$ is an injection.

Comment: Please do not delete your question when it is answered.  The reason for a public q&a site is so that others may benefit in the future.  You can add a note at the end of the question saying you figured it out, however.